# Set Devise Role By Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My app has 3 roles for users: member, handicapper, admin

I'm trying to set the role by the route, example:

```
get '/members/sign_up' => 'devise/registrations#create', :role => 'member'
```

Then in my controller, which I use to override devise, I do something like this:

```
def create
  super do
    resource.role = params[:role]
    resource.save
  end
end
```

Please give some direction as to what I'm doing wrong, or what I else I need to be doing.

Also, I currently don't have a way of checking whether that parameter is even being passed to the action, so if you could suggest ways to do that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have gone through several tutorials and documentation pages, as well as dozens of SO questions, but have yet to find anything this specific.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should add I have already added the field to the migration file, and ran rake db:migrate.
EDIT 2: `User.last` in rails console shows `role: nil`

Comment: Use binding.pry for debugging and localhost:3000/rails/info/routes for checking whether correct routes are being generated or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the role column in the users table I would suggest using enum.

`add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0`

Then in your user model add:

`enum role: {member: 0, handicapper:1, admin: 2}`

Now by default a user will always have a role of member. Don't set a users role via a route - that sounds like a security hole.

If your letting users self register, let them do that and they will be automatically set to member, and then in an admin area you can set their role to something else if need be.